# Генерация карты sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите, чем можно построить sitemap.xml для отправки карты в гугл и в яндекс, может есть сайты, которые генерируют или скрипты/программы.

**Добавлено.**

Генерирую через цикл

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Subdivision WHERE Checked=1");  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);    
$fp = fopen( "sitemap.xml", "w" ) or die ( "Не удалось открыть файл" );  
do {  
fputs( $fp, "<url>  
    <loc>http://site.ru/catalogview.php?id=$row[id]</loc>  
    <priority>1.0</priority>  
    <lastmod>2011-08-31T17:01:25+01:00</lastmod>  
</url>" );  
}while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res));      
fclose( $fp );
```

XML-файл полностью создается, отправляю в гугл, он его опровергает, что не так?

Comment: Что не так - я Вам не подскажу, я его на Django как страницу типа xml формировал... В рнр вообще не секу.

Comment: Список ссылок должен помещаться внутрь тэгов [urlset](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php).

Answer (score 1):

Файл вот так должен выглядеть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
#здесь всё что генерируется вашим циклом#
</urlset>
```

и всё будет в порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Я генерировал вручную на основе их доков, там же нет ничего сложного - просто передаете необходимые данные и формируете из них xml.

Comment: Да я уже начал генерировать по маске, по которой генерирует xml-sitemaps.com. Добавлено в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть список URL, папок веб-сервера или логи веб-сервера на основе которых нужно создать свой sitemap.xml, то подойдет [Google Sitemap Generator](http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/). Также встречаются и сайты, которые сканируют сайт и выдают по результатам sitemap.xml, например, [xml-sitemaps.com](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/).

Comment: А здесь еще целый список: [Web Sitemap Generators](http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators).